# Unable to parent bones (not getting the 'keep offset' option)

Tags: rigging, parent

Here Im trying to parent the hand bone and the shoulder bone to the root bone. But every time I try to parent them the only option i get is "Connected" but i need the the "keep offset" option. If I try to parent it from the object mode using the pipette THIS happens[image]. What am i supposed to do here? I've been trying to follow this tutorial but Im stuck at 2:09 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WjAJHrLGvBE)

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I got it. I just had to select the armature and the root bone and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>J</kbd> in *Object Mode*. Then go to *Edit Mode* and select the bones accordingly.